# How to create a custom datatype which represent list of custom datatype in umbraco?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco7

in Umbraco I want to create a custom data type which represent a dynamic list of Entity which has a content in "RichTextBox"  and a primary image.

I want use this dataType to create a page with a list of related topic witch are not a independent article and are only related to main Article.

how can I create this DataType? is there any solution with combination with Macroes and datatype in Umbraco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a package named Archetype which, if I understand you correctly, will provide you with what you need (a dynamic list of custom datatypes): https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/archetype/

Answer (score 1):

Archetype is a good option but another good option is Nested Content (https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/nested-content/).  It's easy to define the data structure because it uses a Document Type.